# where to locate iostream.h in centos which had installed gcc-c++ rpm?

Tags: c++, centos

where to locate iostream.h in centos which had installed gcc-c++ rpm?

I tried "find / -name iostream.h"

and find in /usr/  /usr/local/include and /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/include manually.

but no any file.

So how to locate the file? what's more,if no this file, how the Centos provide compile for c++?

Comment: Why do you need it? What's wrong with `<iostream>`?

Comment: I only want know where is the iostream.h in centos to understand the c++ find path to include file. 3ks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the iostream header doesn't end with .h which is probably why you weren't able to find it. The quick and dirty answer on how to find out where it is located:

```
rpm -ql libstdc++-devel | grep iostream
/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/iostream
```

I got that by first trying to see if the iostream library was installed with gcc-c++ as you indicated.

```
# if gcc-cc++ is installed
rpm -ql gcc-c++ | grep iostream
# or if gcc-c++ isn't installed
rpm -qlp gcc-c++ | grep iostream
```

Finding nothing I got a list of dependencies for gcc-c++ via the following command.

```
# if gcc-cc++ is installed
rpm -qR gcc-c++
# or if gcc-c++ isn't installed
# no idea
```

Which returns the following on Centos 6.5:

```
gcc = 4.4.7-4.el6
libc.so.6()(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit)  
libdl.so.2()(64bit)  
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libgmp.so.3()(64bit)  
libmpfr.so.1()(64bit)  
libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6
libstdc++-devel = 4.4.7-4.el6
libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)  
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)  
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Making an educated guess that devel rpms typically hold header files I just ran the command I indicated at the beginning and did a grep to get the answer. These are just some general debugging tips that I hope you might find useful while playing around with the Red Hat family of linux.